React spring 3d carousel flickering
When the slide changes my whole carousel blacks out for a millisecond and comes back up (flickering).
It doesn't happen when I use the navigation controls, only when it changes the slide automatically. It also happens when I use the keyboard controls or click on an image to change slides. I don't understand why the whole thing flickers when the slide changes.
`import React, { Component } from "react";
import Carousel from "react-spring-3d-carousel";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './ImageCard.css';

const getTouches = (evt) => {
  return evt.touches || evt.originalEvent.touches;
};
const config = {
  mass: 3, // Adjust mass for inertia-like feel
  tension: 100, // Adjust tension for springiness
  friction: 35, // Adjust friction for damping
};

class ImageCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      goToSlide: 0,
      totalSlides: this.props.images.length,
      intervalId: null,
      config: config.slow,
      intervalDuration: 2000, 
      enableSwipe: true,
      xDown: null,
      yDown: null,
      showNavigation: true,

    };
  }
  

  componentDidMount() {
    const intervalId = setInterval(this.nextSlide, this.state.intervalDuration);
    this.setState({ intervalId });
    window.addEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", this.handleKeyDown);
  }

  nextSlide = () => {
    const { goToSlide, totalSlides } = this.state;
    const nextSlideIndex = (goToSlide + 1) % totalSlides;
    this.setState({ goToSlide: nextSlideIndex });
  }

  generateSlides = () => {
    return this.props.images.map((image, index) => ({
      key: uuidv4(),
      content: (
        <div className="slide-container">
          <div className="image-card-container"> 
            <img src={URL.createObjectURL(image.file)} alt={image.name} />
          </div>
          <div className="info-container">
            <p>{image.name}</p>
            <p>{image.type}</p>
            <p>{image.caption}</p>
            <p>{image.hex}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ),
      onClick: () => this.setState({ goToSlide: index })
    }));
  };

  handleTouchStart = (evt) => {
    if (!this.state.enableSwipe) return;
    const firstTouch = getTouches(evt)[0];
    this.setState({
      xDown: firstTouch.clientX,
      yDown: firstTouch.clientY
    });
  };

  handleTouchMove = (evt) => {
    if (!this.state.enableSwipe || this.state.xDown === null || this.state.yDown === null) return;

    const xUp = evt.touches[0].clientX;
    const yUp = evt.touches[0].clientY;

    const xDiff = this.state.xDown - xUp;
    const yDiff = this.state.yDown - yUp;

    if (Math.abs(xDiff) > Math.abs(yDiff)) {
      if (xDiff > 0) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({ goToSlide: prevState.goToSlide + 1 }));
      } else {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({ goToSlide: prevState.goToSlide - 1 }));
      }
    }

    this.setState({ xDown: null, yDown: null });
  };

  handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 37:
        this.setState((prevState) => ({ goToSlide: prevState.goToSlide - 1 }));
        break;
      case 39:
        this.setState((prevState) => ({ goToSlide: prevState.goToSlide + 1 }));
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  render() {
    const slides = this.generateSlides();

    return (
      <div
        style={{ width: "80%", height: "500px", margin: "0 auto" }}
        onTouchStart={this.handleTouchStart}
        onTouchMove={this.handleTouchMove}
      >
        <div className="carousel-container">
          <Carousel
            slides={slides}
            goToSlide={this.state.goToSlide}
            offsetRadius={10} // Adjust the offset radius as needed
            showNavigation={this.state.showNavigation}
            animationConfig={config}
          />
        </div>

        <div
          style={{
            margin: "0 auto",
            marginTop: "2rem",
            width: "80%",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "space-around"
          }}
        >
          {/* Your input controls go here */}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ImageCard.propTypes = {
  images: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      file: PropTypes.instanceOf(File).isRequired,
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
  ).isRequired
};

export default ImageCard;

I expect no flickering when the slide changes. Can anyone give some advice?
